# How to construct filter based on table binding values?

Tags: sapui5

I have table like this:

```
<Table
    id="table"
    items="{path: invoices}/>
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title id="tableHeader" text="table"/>
            <ToolbarSpacer />
            <Button tooltip="View Settings" icon="sap-icon://drop-down-list" press="handleFilterPressed" />
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
</Table>
```

and the invoices look like this:

```
{
  invoiceid: 1,
  business area: 1
}
{
  invoiceid: 2,
  business area: 2
}
{
  invoiceid: 3,
  business area: 1
}
```

handleFilterPressed looks like this:

```
handleFilterPressed : function(oEvent) {
    if (!this._oDialog) {
        this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("vfb.view.Filter", this);
    }

    // toggle compact style
    jQuery.sap.syncStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact", this.getView(), this._oDialog);               
    this._oDialog.open();
},
```

and the fragment for the filter looks like this:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <ViewSettingsDialog
        confirm="onSetFilter">
        <filterItems>
            <ViewSettingsFilterItem
                text="Business area"
                key="BusArea"
                multiSelect="true"
                id="filterList">
                <items>
                </items>
            </ViewSettingsFilterItem>
        </filterItems>
    </ViewSettingsDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

so now my question: how can i construct the filterlist items based on the data in this way that the filter will look like this:

```
<items>
    <ViewSettingsItem text="1" key="1" />
    <ViewSettingsItem text="2" key="2" />
</items>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do aggregation binding in your fragment:

```
invoices:[
  {
    invoiceid: 1,
    businessArea: 1
  },
  {
    invoiceid: 2,
    businessArea: 2
  },
  {
    invoiceid: 3,
    businessArea: 1
  }
]


<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <ViewSettingsDialog
        confirm="onSetFilter"
        filterItems="{/invoices}">
        <filterItems>
            <ViewSettingsFilterItem
                text="{businessArea}"
                key="{businessArea}">
            </ViewSettingsFilterItem>
        </filterItems>
    </ViewSettingsDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

But, the correct way is to have a node in your JSON model (or entitySet in OData model) which lists the businessAreas. otherwise, if you use your current JSON, you will get duplicates when doing the aggregation binding.
So improve it with something like this:

```
invoices:[
  {
    invoiceid: 1,
    businessArea: 1
  },
  {
    invoiceid: 2,
    businessArea: 2
  },
  {
    invoiceid: 3,
    businessArea: 1
  }
],
businessAreas:[
  {
    businessAreaName: "Business 1"
    businessArea: 1
  },
  {
    businessAreaName: "Business 2"
    businessArea: 2
  }
]


<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <ViewSettingsDialog
        confirm="onSetFilter"
        filterItems="{/businessAreas}">
        <filterItems>
            <ViewSettingsFilterItem
                text="{businessAreaName}"
                key="{businessArea}">
            </ViewSettingsFilterItem>
        </filterItems>
    </ViewSettingsDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I think those small changes will help you.

Comment: ok but i need to add the filters in the items of the ViewSettingsFilterItem. i have tried to use the attribute items from ViewSettingsFilterItem but that attribute seems non existent.

Comment: i have found the method "addItem" but can't i do this in the xml with an attribute of ViewSettingsDialog?

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ViewSettingsFilterItem.html .

ViewSettingsFilterItem have an items aggregation. But it only accepts  sap.m.ViewSettingsItem controls.

So you can do:

`<ViewSettingsFilterItem
                text="{businessAreaName}"
                key="{businessArea}"
                items="{node}">
                   <items>
                        <ViewSettingsItem />
                   </items>
            </ViewSettingsFilterItem>`

Comment: Inside <items> </items> you should define a template with ViewSettingsItem as control, setting its properties

Comment: now i have [this](http://jsbin.com/mijasabejo/edit?html) and i get ViewSettingsFilterItem but when i click on it i get no ViewSettingsItem. it just says "no data". in the debugger on the network tab i see that there is no call to the service. and on the items i tried: { path: '/BusAreaFilterSet' }, {/BusAreaFilterSet}, {'/BusAreaFilterSet'}